# angular 2 - subscribe function called twice

Tags: angular

I have this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewService } from './view.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.css'],
  providers: [ViewService]
})
    export class ViewComponent {

      constructor(viewService: ViewService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.route.params.map(params => params['id']).subscribe((id) => {
            console.log("id: "  + id);
        });

      }
    }
```

I have subscribed my code to the run parameters.
The thing is - subscribe function is called **twice** - 
First time - id is undefined.
Second time - id value exists.

What could be the cause for this issue?

Comment: why are you using `map` in `this.route.params.map(....` ?

Comment: It's just to map the value. can be removed. but does not really change the matter

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I am running into the same thing

Comment: @cgatian Yes I did solve the issue, and added my solution in the answers below. try to check if you are calling ctor twice in html/routing

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. I found my issue to be caused by using a cold observable and subscribing twice.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here was that my ViewComponent was loaded twice. that's why the constructor was called twice:

1. In my `app.module.ts` when defining routing. here:

   `RouterModule.forRoot([
   { path: '', component: ViewComponent }`
2. in my app.component.html - I added `<app-view>` tag.

Comment: thanks for posting this, really simple in the end as usual!

Comment: For those finding your constructor loading twice, it could also be that one is bootstrapping child components in the module.